# Cannot set reference to RefEdit Form Control

Tags: forms, vba, excel

When dealing with UserForm input, I prefer to create objects and set them equal to the various controls. Despite my best efforts, I cannot set a reference to a RefEdit control without triggering a compile error. I have checked that I have the correct references, tried both the options provided in Intellisense and exhausted my google-fu. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does `Dim cellSelectionBox As RefEdit.RefEdit` work? That highlighted `RefEdit` in your IntelliSense menu looks like a library to me, the one underneath looks like the data type

Comment: Yes. That's fixed everything. Now make that an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I wish MSDN would include documentation on how to reference objects. Trying to google examples is incredibly hit and miss.

Comment: fwiw, I think MS are making a good effort to clean up/enhance the MSDN documentation as a lot of the pages now show links to the GitHub repo where you can suggest edits and improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RefEdit` in your [intellisense](/questions/tagged/intellisense) menu (highlighted) is the object library - and you need the data type (which is the one listed below it in the same menu).

Try:

```
Dim cellSelectionBox As RefEdit.RefEdit
```